# FFT on real 2d data

Tags: fftw

I am trying to understand the output of a `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d`

Input data:

```
    for(uint32_t row = 0; row < img.height(); ++row)
    {
        for(uint32_t col = 0; col < img.width(); ++col)
        {
            auto y = static_cast<float>(row)/img.height();
            auto x = static_cast<float>(col)/img.width();
            constexpr auto f = 4.0f;
            img.get(col, row) = sin(2.0f*M_PI*f*y) + cos(2.0f*M_PI*f*x);
        }
    }
```

Output: white indicates that `abs(val) > 0.1f`:

[image: magnitude of fft output]

Here are the real and imaginary parts of the highlighted points:

```
(2048, -4.556181e-14)
(-2.743209e-14, -2048)
(-2.743209e-14, 2048)
```

Is the lower half always complex conjugate of the upper half, or are there more frequencies in one direction? Input image is 64x64 pixels. I assume that the right half of the transformed image is compex conjgate of the left half. Thus a r2c can omit that part.

Answer (score 0):

For real input data (imaginary part is zero, like in your example) it is.

According to [this site](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Symmetry_DTFT_Real_Signals.html):

*"In other terms, if a signal x(n) is real, then its spectrum is Hermitian (conjugate symmetric)."*

When working with real input data, I have only dealt with the first half of the result array.  *r[0]* will always be real and represents the DC offset of the signal; `r[N/2]` represents the Nyquist frequency (the maximum representable frequency at the discrete signal's sampling rate).

[This site](https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2015/11/interpreting-fft-results-complex-dft-frequency-bins-and-fftshift/) does a nice explanation on how to interpret the results of a FFT.

**EDIT: added reference to multidimensional case:**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_real-input_multidimensional_DFT), yes, the multidimensional case also exhibits conjugate symmetry, although I could not find a citation reference to confirm this.

*"The real-input multidimensional DFT
For input data Xn1, n2,...nd consisting of real numbers, the DFT outputs have a conjugate symmetry similar to the one-dimensional case above... "*

Comment: I am familiar with 1d data, but I am not so sure about how 2d data behaves. That is why I explicitly ask about 2d (generalization to higher dimensions is also interesting),